# Jsoup. Как выбрать методом select элемент, который подписан как <a64:div .... >

Tags: java, html, jsoup

Имеется страничка к примеру с таким кодом.

```
<a64:div class="branches">bla-bla</a64:div>
```

Как мне достать текст с этого блока?

```
document.select("div.branches");
document.select("a64:div.branches");
```

Так не получается, первый способ ничего не выводит, второй кидает ошибку

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подобный элемент можно извлечь задав пространство имен|тег (через вертикальную черту)

```
Elements items = document.select("a64|div.branches");
```

---

Также, вы можете обратиться к атрибуту **.class** без указания тега

```
Elements items = document.select(".branches");
```

Comment: Спасибо, но там есть подобные элементы без классов и других идентификаторов, как мне выбрать их?

Comment: Подобный элемент можно извлечь задав **пространство имен|тег** (через вертикальную черту) `Elements items = document.select("a64|div.branches");`

Comment: Мануал по извлечению элементов в **Jsoup** http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за помощь! Я просто с html не знаком, так что даже не знал что искать.